# opera snap has stopped connecting with paid VPN on

Tags: networking, unity, vpn, opera

Have been using Opera snap version for over a week now.  This morning it has stopped connecting to internet when using Windscribe VPN(whole system), connects without VPN.

The odd thing is that 'private window' is still connecting to internet with VPN.

System was not shut down over night, so no updates occurred.

Using Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.4.0-64-generic with unity desktop, wired connection.  Last set of updates are asking for restart, delaying for a day or two.

VPN is accessed though network manager.

Did some googling and could only similar problem with stopify(?) snap and expressvpn caused by resolve.conf being messed up

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `snaps` person for this reason. Too walled off. Install it via the .deb from [here](https://www.opera.com/download)

Comment: Already have Opera deb, but it has problems playing facebook and some news sites videos, which the snap version plays well.  Was working well with VPN up to this morning.